# Как обработать значение null в JSON при десериализации в C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp

Есть приходящий JSON:
    `{ key: null }` (вообще там обычно число но бывает прилетает и `null`).
В модели у `key` тип `long`.
Соответственно когда я делаю
    `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json)`
у меня вылетает ошибка конвертирования!
Есть для этого какое то красивое решение чтобы не обрабатывать каждое свойство?

Comment: `long` => `long?`

Comment: `try { .. } catch() {} ` и все пройдет :) там ещё куча ошибок может быть, при не совпадении источника и модели, все не предусмотреть..

Comment: Как по мне, два самых лучших варианта - это либо `long?` либо переопределить `NullValueHandling` у `JsonSerializerSettings` (пример: [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813055/how-to-handle-null-empty-values-in-jsonconvert-deserializeobject)), что сделает игнорирование таких ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите сделать с этой ошибкой. Если вам важно понять, что пришедший JSON не соответствует вашей модели, то просто реализуется блок try

```
try
{
  // Десереализация JSON
}
catch
{
  // Обработка сценария, когда JSON не соотвествует модели
}
```

Если вам надо десериализовать объект в любом случае, а с полями будете разбираться потом, то все поля [value-типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) необходимо сделать Nullable:

```
public long? Key { get; set; }
```

В этом случае у вас десереализация будет проходить штатно, но вот когда вы будете данные обрабатывать, надо быть готовым, что часть полей теперь будет содержать null.

P.s. Использование предложенного в комментариях варианта с игнорирование null через настройки, не рекомендую, т.к. в этом случае вы не сможете отличить реальные данные полученные из json, от данных которые прописались по умолчанию из-за игнорирования null.